# Filter Dataframe Based on Highest and Lowest Row Values with Increasing Timeline

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe of students with their exam scores in different dates (sorted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student': 'A A A A B B B C C D D'.split(),
                  'exam_date':[datetime.datetime(2013,4,1),datetime.datetime(2013,6,1),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,7,1),datetime.datetime(2013,9,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,10,1),datetime.datetime(2013,11,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2014,2,2),datetime.datetime(2014,5,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2014,6,2), datetime.datetime(2013,7,1),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,9,2),],
                   'score': [15, 22, 32, 20, 30, 38, 26, 18, 30, 33, 40]})

print(df)

   student  exam_date  score
0        A 2013-04-01     15
1        A 2013-06-01     22
2        A 2013-07-01     32
3        A 2013-09-02     20
4        B 2013-10-01     30
5        B 2013-11-02     38
6        B 2014-02-02     26
7        C 2014-05-02     18
8        C 2014-06-02     30
9        D 2013-07-01     33
10       D 2013-09-02     40
```

I need to keep only those rows where the highest score is increased by more than 10 from the lowest score, otherwise drop them. Here, date is also important. The highest score has to be in the latter date than the previous date.

For example, for the student `A`, the lowest score is `15` and the score is increased to `32` (latter in the date), so we're gonna keep that.

For the student `B`, the lowest score is `26`, but there no score is increased after that. It is basically decreased, so we're gonna drop that.

For the student `D`, the lowest score is `33` and the score is increased to `40`, Increase of only `7`, so we're gonna drop that.

I first tried `df.groupby('student').agg({'score': np.ptp})` but it was tough to track if the score is decreased or increased.

Then I tried to use `df.loc[df.groupby('student')['score'].idxmin()]` and `df.loc[df.groupby('student')['score'].idxmax()]` to get the min and values, but not sure how I would compare the dates. Maybe I merge them and then compare, but it's too much of work.

**Desired output:**

```
student exam_date   score
2   A   2013-07-01  32
8   C   2014-06-02  30

#--For A, highest score of 32 increased by 17 from lowest score of 15  
#--For C, highest score of 30 increased by 12 from lowest score of 18
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if there are multiple local maximums ? e.g `10, 30, 15, 35` ?

Comment: Hi @Psidom, in that scenario, we're gonna keep the row when we get the 1st maximum.

Comment: So it would 30 in this case ?

Comment: Yes @Psidom. If in the timeline (lowest to highest), there is an increase of 10. It's included.

Comment: You changed `18` of `C` to `28`, which invalidates your expected output, right?  Because `30 - 28 = 2`

Comment: Yeah @richardec, I was just trying to change the test case but forgot to change later. Your solution is great. Thank you for your time. Appreciate!

Comment: Does my solution work on your real data? I'm curious, because it was half a guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your case first filter by the min point

```
df = df[df.index>=df.groupby('student')['score'].transform('idxmin')]
out = df[df.score - df.groupby('student').score.transform('min')>10]
Out[77]: 
  student  exam_date  score
2       A 2013-07-01     32
8       C 2014-06-02     30
```

Comment: Hi @BENY, thank you for your reply. If the first score of `C` was 28, and the second score 30. It was an increase of 2 and you script would still pick `C`.

Comment: @Roy should it pick the max after the min  ?

Comment: Yes @BENY, it should pick the max after the min.

Comment: @Roy then `If the first score of C was 28, and the second score 30. It was an increase of 2 and you script would still pick C` what is your question ?

Comment: @BENY "I need to keep only those rows where the highest score is increased by more than 10 from the lowest score" - but for `C`, 30 (the highest) minus 28 (the lowest) is 2, so your code should omit `C`.

Comment: @richardec ok update ~

Comment: @BENY Yep, that works now. Upvote coming tomorrow (used up all my votes today)... ;)

Comment: It seems yours one is the robust one, @BENY. Would you please explain the steps a little. Thank you so much! Appreciate your time.

Comment: @Roy First filter the each group by only select the row after min, the we select the left row whose value is greater than the min 10

Comment: Perfect @BENY. Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: Hi @BENY, I'm thinking about another problem. This is basically for global minima and maxima. What about the local minima and maxima. Whenever, we observe a rise of 10 from the local minima, we select that row. How should we proceed? [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949306/ ]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is already sorted by date:

```
highest_score = lambda x: x['score'].cummax() * (x['score'] > x['score'].shift()) \
                          - (x['score'].cummin()) >= 10

out = df[df.groupby('student').apply(highest_score).droplevel(0)]
print(out)

# Output:
  student  exam_date  score
2       A 2013-07-01     32
8       C 2014-06-02     30
```

The expression `* (x['score'] > x['score'].shift())` avoid `cummax` to be propagated if the next value is lower than the current max.

Comment: @Roy. I tested my answer *if the first score of C was 28, and the second score 30*, it worked but do you have another test case?

Comment: Hi @corralien, I'm trying to replicate your this answer here: [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949306/ ]. Would you please suggest a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question is somewhat confusing, but this works for your sample data:

```
subset = df.loc[df.groupby('student').apply(lambda x: x['score'].idxmax() if x.sort_values('exam_date')['score'].diff().max() >= 10 else None).dropna().astype(int)]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
  student  exam_date  score
2       A 2013-07-01     32
```

Comment: Hi @richardec. Thank you so much for solution. It perfectly worked. Appreciate. I picked Corralien's as it's easy to explain :)

Comment: Really, you think so? That's fine :) but mine seems pretty easy to explain: it computes the different between each value and its previous value, and if there is a difference of 10 or more between one row and the next anywhere in the group, return the row from that group with the highest `score`. That's all ;)