# Filter Dataframe Based on Local Minima with Increasing Timeline

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-manipulation

EDITED:

I have the following dataframe of students with their exam scores in different dates (sorted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student': 'A A A B B B B C C'.split(),
                  'exam_date':[datetime.datetime(2013,4,1),datetime.datetime(2013,6,1),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,7,1),datetime.datetime(2013,9,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,10,1),datetime.datetime(2013,11,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2014,2,2),datetime.datetime(2013,7,1),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,9,2),],
                   'score': [15, 17, 32, 22, 28, 24, 33, 33, 15]})

print(df)

  student  exam_date  score
0       A 2013-04-01     15
1       A 2013-06-01     17
2       A 2013-07-01     32
3       B 2013-09-02     22
4       B 2013-10-01     28
5       B 2013-11-02     24
6       B 2014-02-02     33
7       C 2013-07-01     33
8       C 2013-09-02     15
```

I need to keep only those rows where the score is increased by more than 10 from the local minima.

For example, for the student `A`, the local minima is `15` and the score is increased to `32` in the next-to-to date, so we're gonna keep that.

For the student `B`, no score is increased by more than `10` from local minima. `28-22` and `33-24` both are less than `10`.

For the student `C`, the local minima is `15`, but the score isn't increased after that, so we're gonna drop that.

I'm trying the following script:

```
out = df[df['score'] - df.groupby('student', as_index=False)['score'].cummin()['score']>= 10]

print(out)
2   A   2013-07-01  32
6   B   2014-02-02  33 #--Shouldn't capture this as it's increased by `9` from local minima of `24`
```

**Desired output:**

```
   student  exam_date  score
2        A  2013-07-01  32

# For A, score of 32 is increased by 17 from local minima of 15
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is already sorted by date:

```
highest_score = lambda x: x['score'] - x['score'].mask(x['score'].gt(x['score'].shift())).ffill() > 10
out = df[df.groupby('student').apply(highest_score).droplevel(0)]
print(out)

# Output
  student  exam_date  score
2       A 2013-07-01     32
```

**Focus on lambda function**

Let's modify your dataframe and extract one student to avoid `groupby`:

```
>>> df = df[df['student'] == 'B']
  student  exam_date  score
3       B 2013-09-02     22
4       B 2013-10-01     28
5       B 2013-11-02     24
6       B 2014-02-02     33

# Step-1: find row where value is not a local minima
>>> df['score'].gt(df['score'].shift())
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
Name: score, dtype: bool

# Step-2: hide non local minima values
>>> df['score'].mask(df['score'].gt(df['score'].shift()))
3    22.0
4     NaN
5    24.0
6     NaN
Name: score, dtype: float64

# Step-3: fill forward local minima values
>>> df['score'].mask(df['score'].gt(df['score'].shift()))
3    22.0
4    22.0
5    24.0
6    24.0
Name: score, dtype: float64

# Step-4: check if the condition is True
>>> df['score'] - df['score'].mask(df['score'].gt(df['score'].shift())) > 10
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: score, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you @corralien. It works with all edge cases. I'd like to know a little more about this part `mask(x['score'].gt(x['score'].shift()))`

Comment: I have a doubt on my answer... If I replace 17 by 28 on the second row, this row is now selected but it's not the local maxima. Right? So I have to compute the local maxima

Comment: Yes, it's completely fine. The first instance where the rise is observed. `(28-15)=13>10`. It's basically the difference from local minima to all the above numbers and keep the more than 10 difference.

Comment: This is not the definition of a local maxima because 28 < 32. In this case, should I return both rows (28 and 32) or the first (28) or the higher of two (32)?

Comment: IIUC your comment, I should return both rows so my answer is right.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't say local maxima. It's the difference of all the scores after local minima and keeping the row where the 1st rise of 10 is observed.

Comment: Ok I get it. I will give you some explanation about `x['score'].mask(x['score'].gt(x['score'].shift())).ffill()`

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if my explanation are sufficient or not :)

Comment: It's so awesome @corralien. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

We could try the following:

1. Find the difference between consecutive scores for each student using `groupby` + `diff`.
2. using `where`, assign NaN values to all rows where the score difference is less than 10
3. use `groupby` + `first` to get the first score differences greater than 10 for each student.

```
msk = (diff>10) | (diff.groupby([diff[::-1].shift().lt(0).cumsum()[::-1], df['student']]).cumsum()>10)
out = df.where(msk).groupby('student').first().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  student  exam_date  score
0       A 2013-06-01   27.0
1       B 2013-10-01   43.0
```

Comment: Wow, this is so, so much better than mine. Nice job!! :D

Comment: @richardec thanks for the edit, this looks much more readable; and thanks for backing me on the other post :-)

Comment: You're welcome on both! I'm happy to nag new users about accepting...it's a comment I write so often... :P

Comment: Hi @enke, thank you for your response. It works in this use case. However, if we change the values of `A` with `15, 20, 26`, the code misses to capture `26`, which is increased by `11` from local minima (`15`).

Comment: @Roy updated the solution. see if it works now. it now captures 26 in that example. see if it works now

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating @Corralien's solution you posted, I've come up with a one-liner that works nicely:

```
filtered = df.groupby('student', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: None if (v := (x['score'].cummax() * (x['score'] > x['score'].shift()) - (x['score'].cummin()) >= 10)).sum() == 0 else x.loc[v.idxmax()] ).dropna()
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
  student  exam_date  score
0       A 2013-06-01   27.0
1       B 2013-10-01   43.0
```

Comment: Thanks @richardec. May you break your code so I understand what's going on. Sorry, enke's one isn't robust when there is multiple observations between local minima and local maxima.

Comment: @Roy I'll try to explain more tomorrow (bed time here :), but basically what it does is it groups by `student`, and for each group, selects the row come immediately after the row with the mininum `score` for that group. If the `score` for the row coming after the minimum is more than `10` higher than the min score, that row and only that row of the group is selected. Otherwise, none of the rows are selected.